# Trying to copy dir into server but server gets full even if the folder is smaller than the free space on disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, scp

**Problem**

I'm trying to copy a directory with 112 GB to a RAID on a server which has 214 GB of free space using `scp`. However, after copying some files, I receive a message telling me the disk is full, and after verifying, I can see the disk is actually full. I don't understand how this is possible and I would like to understand and solve it.

**Details**

I'm using CentOS 7. I just installed the OS on the raid before trying to copy the directory. This is the output of `df -h` right after installing it:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  897M   50G   2% /
devtmpfs                 7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7,8G  8,9M  7,8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               1014M  143M  872M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home  214G   33M  214G   1% /home
tmpfs                    1,6G     0  1,6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

I'm trying to copy the dir via scp from my notebook which runs ubuntu 17.04. This is the size of the dir:

```
rick@rick-Inspiron-5448:~$ sudo du -hs /home/rick/
112G    /home/rick/
```

As you can see, there is a little bit less than 214 GB of free space at the server RAID, and the dir I'm trying to copy has only 112 GB.

I copy it by using

```
$ scp -r /home/rick/ user@192.168.0.132:/home/user/backup
```

It works fine for a few hours and then I receive the following output repeatedly:

```
scp: /home/user/backup/rick/<filename>: No space left on device
```

If I then type `df -h` I can verify that the disk is actually full!

```
[user@localhost ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  897M   50G   2% /
devtmpfs                 7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7,8G  8,8M  7,8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               1014M  143M  872M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home  214G  214G   20K 100% /home
tmpfs                    1,6G     0  1,6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

So what I understand from this id that I tried to copy 112 GB on a disk which has 214 GB free, but somehow the disk got filled before the copy was completed. I know I'm missing something here, but I can't see what.

This is the information about the RAID I configured on the server:

[image: RAID Information]

If there is any other detail I can provide to clarify my situation, just let me know.

---

**Update**

@AFH comment suggested the problem could be related to the i-nodes, so I ran

```
$ df -i
Filesystem                Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root 26214400  25686 26188714    1% /
devtmpfs                 2024232    474  2023758    1% /dev
tmpfs                    2026995      1  2026994    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    2026995    579  2026416    1% /run
tmpfs                    2026995     16  2026979    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                 524288    328   523960    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home   127080 126903      177  100% /home
tmpfs                    2026995      1  2026994    1% /run/user/1000
```

Also, output of `fdisk`

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 292.3 GB, 292326211584 bytes, 570949632 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b2997

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   570949631   284425216   8e  Linux LVM
```

So, in fact, inodes are full. Any suggestions about how to solve it?

Comment: So did you check what arrived at the destination? Use `du` on the target directory.

Comment: `du` is aware of hardlinks and doesn't count them more than once. After `scp` the files on the destination are not hardlinked anymore. Also `du` doesn't follow symlinks, `scp` does, I think. But what is your question?

Comment: A disc will appear full if it runs out of i-nodes, even if it has unused data space.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [clusters](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Data_cluster)?

Comment: @AFH Thank you for the clue. I had never heard about i-nodes before, so I'm reading about it. In the meanwhile, do you know if there is a way to configure the raid to use all unused data space - or at least more of it?

Comment: Have you got "sparse files"? See rsync's `-S, --sparse` option.

Comment: @IporSircer never heard about it, but just checked out. I found [this](https://ibb.co/by2BaG)  on my server,  which says strip size is 64kB. I believe most of my files are bigger than that, but I will check how much space I'm losing because of this.

Comment: @AFH it seems that inodes are really related to it. I updated the post with more info.

Comment: You might investigate alternative file systems with lower overhead. Some of the difference is accounted for by the difference between GB and GiB - I don't know which figure the BIOS is reporting, but `df -h` reports GiB. Have a look at `sudo fdisk -l` for more clarification.

Comment: This is the well known _cookie-effect_ - 100g of cookies can produce 200g of crumbs when eaten in bed ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I figured out how to solve the problem. The problem was that when I used `scp` to copy the files, the folder containing `wine` had a completely different size at the destination then it had at the source.

I'm not sure if that was related to `wine` copy occupying more i-nodes than it should, or if wine was being recursively copied inside its folder, but when I checked with `df -h`, `wine` folder had 1.5GB at the source and 101GB at the server, which was the destiny of `scp`.

I cleared the disk at the server and did the backup using `rsync` instead of `scp` and it worked just fine.

Thank you for everybody who helped, it was a hard weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Does your backup copy has symlinks?
If yes, then use rsync to copy the contents.
Scp with -r option follows the symbolic links as well.

Answer (score 0):

> So, in fact, inodes are full. Any suggestions about how to solve it?

You cannot increase the number of inodes without reformatting the filesystem.

Currently you have about 120 GB of space you can't use because you don't have the inodes for it.

What you can try is:

- reduce the size of the filesystem on the LVM partition (DANGEROUS) by about 110 GB using e.g. `resize2fs`,
- reduce the LVM partition to exactly fit the filesystem (also dangerous),
- create a new partition in the free space
- the new partition can now be mounted.

You could for example see whether you have a few directories that could fit in 110 GB of space (/home/user/downloads and so on), move the content of that directory in the new partition, then mount the partition in the old directory. You now have a free space (and inodes) available equal to the size of the moved files.

The whole operation needs careful planning and I strongly recommend a full backup.